# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId on pusher api

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, pusher

I would like to ask how to fix this because I tried researching it but, none of the answers I found on the web worked for me. I'm still registering the device for use on the pusher website and when I copy this code the error pop up.

```
PushNotifications.start(getApplicationContext(), "mykey"); PushNotifications.addDeviceInterest("hello");
```

Here is my project Gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
} }
```

And my app Gradle

```
dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:20.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.4'
implementation 'com.pusher:push-notifications-android:1.6.2'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'} apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and lastly here's my java class

```
public class Sprinkler extends AppCompatActivity {

Button On;
Button Off;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.sprinkler);

    PushNotifications.start(getApplicationContext(), "mykey");
    PushNotifications.addDeviceInterest("hello");

    On = (Button) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    Off = (Button) findViewById(R.id.switch2);
    On.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // getting the default FirebaseDatabase instance
            FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

            // getting a DatabaseReference for the database root node
            DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Relay_Status");

            databaseReference.setValue(1);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sprinkler Turn On!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); } }); }
```

and here's the error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.fire_app, PID: 24128
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId;
    at com.pusher.pushnotifications.PushNotificationsInstance.start(PushNotificationsInstance.kt:180)
    at com.pusher.pushnotifications.PushNotifications.start(PushNotifications.java:31)
    at com.example.fire_app.Sprinkler.onCreate(Sprinkler.java:27)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.fire_app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at com.pusher.pushnotifications.PushNotificationsInstance.start(PushNotificationsInstance.kt:180) 
    at com.pusher.pushnotifications.PushNotifications.start(PushNotifications.java:31) 
    at com.example.fire_app.Sprinkler.onCreate(Sprinkler.java:27) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 17 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using a `firebase:firebase-messaging` version above 22.0 you will need to ensure you also add these lines to your app gradle

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0"
implementation 'com.pusher:push-notifications-android:1.9.0'

// Add this line to the end of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[Source](https://github.com/pusher/push-notifications-android#update-your-app-level-gradle-config).

Comment: thanks for the answer my app is running again. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

**This issue has been resolved with the following releases which are now live:**

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.3.5
com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx:18.3.5
com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ndk:18.3.5
com.google.firebase:firebase-installations:17.1.2
com.google.firebase:firebase-installations-ktx:17.1.2
```

It is safe to update these dependencies and remove the above workarounds, if needed. Note that using the Firebase BoM is the recommended way to control Firebase library versions (the latest BoM is v31.2.2).

Reference:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/4683#issuecomment-1432270489